# Copy Ir Remote Data from Remote Control to Mobile App

Tags: android

I want to copy Data from an IR Remote and save the Data to an assigned button on the mobile app
and use it as universal remote just like the video given below
Can any one please guide me how to code this functionality
or is there any app similar to this app already on the play store

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Faez94MOw0A

And the app that is shown on this video is for this mobile phone only
which is not available on the play store

I tried to find this specific app and tried to side load this app onto my phone but it was not getting installed. It might be because it is very old app and haven't been updated for very long time.